# MySQL grouping by Date()

Tags: mysql

Hey i've created a rather larger query which calculate the yield and the balance. This data i use for creating a line graph. However i've come to a point where i feel it is rather clumsy to have all this in a line graph instead of want group or merge together records with same date. Basically it should only show the last record of each day. an illustration of the output i want. The right is the current. the left is what i want. As you can see the left one has removed all the records which is not last one on each day.

[image]

```
SET @balance = 0;
SET @yield = 0;

SELECT *, 
    CASE WHEN stats =  'wrong'
    THEN @balance := @balance -100
    ELSE @balance := @balance + ( odds * 100 - 100 ) 
    END as balance,
    CASE WHEN stats =  'wrong'
            THEN @yield := @yield + ( 0 / 100) *100
            ELSE @yield := @yield + ( odds / 100) * 100
    END as yield
    FROM (SELECT odds.meta_value AS odds, stat.meta_value AS stats, posts.post_date
            FROM wp_t3a673_posts posts
            LEFT JOIN wp_t3a673_postmeta stat ON posts.ID = stat.post_id
            AND stat.meta_key =  'status'
            LEFT JOIN wp_t3a673_postmeta odds ON posts.ID = odds.post_id
            AND odds.meta_key =  'odds'
            LEFT JOIN wp_t3a673_term_relationships tr ON posts.ID = tr.object_id
            LEFT JOIN wp_t3a673_term_taxonomy t ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = t.term_taxonomy_id
            WHERE (
            stat.meta_value =  'correct'
            OR stat.meta_value =  'wrong'
            )
            AND posts.post_status =  'publish'
            AND t.taxonomy =  'category'
            AND (
            t.term_id =4
            OR t.term_id =5
            OR t.term_id =6
            )
    ORDER BY posts.post_date
    ) tt
```

php

```
foreach ($balanceQuery as $row) 
{ 

    $value = $row->balance;


    $datetime = strtotime($row->post_date) * 1000;
    $data[] = "[$datetime, $value]";
}
```

Comment: What if you get the data, put it in an array and if a new date comes destroy previous?

Comment: Unfortunatly i use the data elsewhere so if it delete it from the system i would not be able to get it there

Comment: Or are you thinking specifically in this query?

Comment: No, I ment deleting from the array you create when fetching the data. Are you fetching the data only with Mysql? No php, RoR,...?

Comment: That is possible i've added my php where $balancequery is the output of the the query.

Comment: You should then be able to compare `$value` and `$datetime` with the previous records. If date is before splice it from the array, then add the new one...

Comment: You mean the other left and the other right, right? (or should I say, left ;-))